# Change network data source for single layer from local network dataset to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, network-analyst, data-source

I'm working on a project in ArcGIS Pro using the Service Area feature of the Network Analyst extension. Initially, I created a service area layer with a local network data set, StreetMap Premium, but I no longer have access to that data. Further, I didn't export the feature as a shapefile. So currently the service area layer is sitting in my project file with a red exclamation point next to its name and won't show up since it's not connected to the data source. Is it possible to now change the data source for that specific layer to the ArcGIS Online Portal so that I can use it again? The network data source for the project file is already set to the ArcGIS Online Portal but it only works for new network analyst layers. My previous service area requires a very large amount of credits so I unfortunately can't rerun the analysis with the online portal.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to get to the result service area data I don't think you really need to reset\fix the ND.  The solved data should still be in you Pro project's "default" gdb, its just not displaying

So you can either

1. In the Table of Contents view export the feature classes you want, so for example you can export the polygons, as below, to diff feature class or to a shape file.

[image: Table of Contents]

2. Using Catalog window look at the Pro project's default data base and in there should be 1 or more feature dataset where the solve results were written to. You could add those to a new map or copy them out to a diff gdb or shape file.

[image: Default database]

Note: If you've done more that 1 solve there will probably be more than 1 result feature dataset (as the screenshot above does).  So you can look at the "Source" properties of the network analysis layers to determine which feature dataset it refers to (e.g. right click on Polygons layer under "Service Area" group layer > select Properties > Source and the "Feature Dataset" entry should have the feature dataset's name, as in my case like in the screenshot above the particular network analysis I'm look at is using the `ServiceAreaSolveru5ej60` feature dataset to write results to).